# Any recourse in recouping locksmith charge?

Tags: new-york, cash, refund

Was locked out of my apartment with no way to re-enter and needed to get in. Locksmith refused to quote me any amount prior to arriving. After they arrived (30 minutes later), they informed me that drilling the cylinder would cost $400. After drilling the cylinder and opening the door, they informed me the replacement cylinder would cost $450. Having no choice (as I was moving out the following day, needed to have the apartment vacant, and now had a key cylinder with drill holes in it) I paid this. After fees and taxes, this came out to $960. This honestly feels like I was robbed and it feels pretty terrible.

Do I have any recourse here? Can I ask the bank to rescind part of this or something? Or am I just SOL? I don't really have any argument outside of "this is a ludicrous amount to charge me in a situation where I had few if any alternatives".

I signed the receipt and paid via Zelle, if that matters.

Comment: there's a law against price gouging in New York, maybe reach out to the regulators? Was the locksmith licensed?

Comment: Where are you located? That's high even for NYC prices. Though I presume the "trip charge" was built into at least one of those numbers, and I'd bet that's high in places like NYC. Also, it's a question of what quality of lock these were -- high security costs more both to defeat and to replace -- and how much work they had to do to make the cylinder compatible with existing keys (if that was part if the job being done). ... Even with all those qualifications, it sounds like you paid a big price for "do it now".

Comment: Not an answer per se, and a bit late now, but advice for the future and for others: If you have a friend (preferably nearby) whom you trust, trade spare keys with them. Then if either of you gets locked out the other can play rescuer. Usually faster and less expensive than a locksmith even if you have to buy them a thank-you dinner. An ounce of preparation...